# Call mutation before every action Vuex

Tags: ajax, vue.js, action, vuex

Vuex allows us to write plugins that do something whenever a mutation is committed. Is there any way to have a similar functionality, but with actions?

I notice you can "enhance" actions like the [vuexfire library](https://github.com/posva/vuexfire) does, is this the best way to do so?

My goal is to have some way to track if/how many ajax calls are currently pending, and automatically show some kind of animation based on that number.

Edit: To clarify, I am wondering if there is a way to do this using just Vuex, without pulling into additional libraries.

Comment: Are you asking for a recommendation for a library/product, or how to do it yourself?

Comment: Sorry, how to do it myself. I have seen a few libs out there, most wrap all existing actions in an additional function to handle the mutation. At this point that seems the only option, but I wanted to check if anyone else has done something along these lines first. Redux, for example, allows this using it's middleware, although I guess Vuex does not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of Vuex v2.5 you can call `subscribeAction` to register a callback function which will be called after each dispatched action in the store.

The callback will receive an `action` descriptor (object with `type` and `payload` properties) as its first argument and the store's `state` as the second argument.

The documentation for this is on the [Vuex API Reference page](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/api.html).

For example:

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  plugins: [(store) => {
    store.subscribeAction((action, state) => {
      console.log("Action Type: ", action.type)
      console.log("Action Payload: ", action.payload)
      console.log("Current State: ", state)
    })
  }],
  state: {
    foo: 1
  },
  mutations: {
    INCREASE_FOO(state) {
      state.foo++;
    },
  },
  actions: {
    increaseFoo({ commit }) {
      commit('INCREASE_FOO');
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store,
  methods: {
    onClick() {
      this.$store.dispatch('increaseFoo');
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.2/vue.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vuex/3.0.1/vuex.min.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  Foo state: {{ $store.state.foo }}
  <button @click="onClick">Increase Foo</button>
</div>
```

Comment: perfect. I didn't know this was in vuex, relatively recent addition. Thanks!

Comment: what if I need to run something before and after every action? like setting loader status in active or inactive state

Answer (score 1):

Since 3.1.0, subscribeAction can also specify whether the subscribe handler should be called before or after an action dispatch (the default behavior is before):

```
store.subscribeAction({
  before: (action, state) => {
    console.log(`before action ${action.type}`)
  },
  after: (action, state) => {
    console.log(`after action ${action.type}`)
  }
})
```

documentation: https://vuex.vuejs.org/api/#subscribeaction